# Cannot set src property of null

Tags: javascript, html

Keeps telling me i can't set "src property of null". please help me resolve this issue that i currently have. I have no idea because i created those ids but it's telling me that they dont't exist. I do not understand this.

```js
var pot = 100;
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "New Game <br> Pot: $" + pot;
document.getElementById("reset").disabled = true;

function pull() {
  var slot1 = 0;
  var slot2 = 0;
  var slot3 = 0;
  var slot4 = 0;
  /*generate 3 random numbers, assign to corresponding img1,
  img2,img3, swap images in table */
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var fruit = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    document.getElementById(i).src = "img" + fruit + ".gif";
    //assign each of the 3 random numbers to a slot value
    if (i == 1) {
      slot1 = fruit;
    } else if (i == 2) {
      slot2 = fruit;
    } else if (i == 3) {
      slot3 = fruit;
    } else {
      slot4 = fruit;
    }
  }
  //add 25 to the pot if the result is 3 of a kind
  if (slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot4 || slot2 == slot3 && slot3 == slot4) {
    pot = pot + 25;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =
      "Jackpot, 3 of a kind! You win $25.00, <br> Pot: $" + pot;
  }
  //add 50 to pot if they get four of a kind
  else if (slot1 == slot2 && slot3 == slot4 && slot2 == slot3 && slot4 == slot1) {
    pot = pot + 50;
  }
  //add 10 to pot if the result is a pair
  else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot2 == slot3 || slot1 == slot3) {
    pot = pot + 10;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "A pair! You win $10.00. <br> pot: $" + pot;
  } else {
    pot = pot - 120;
    if (pot <= 0) {
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "pot is empty, you are out of cash.";
      document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("reset").disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "No match! You loose         $20.00. <br> Pot: $" + pot;
    }
  }
}

function start() {
  pot = 100;
  document.getElementById("reset").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "New Game <br>     Pot: $" + pot;
  document.getElementById(1).src = "img0.gif";
  document.getElementById(2).src = "img0.gif";
  document.getElementById(3).src = "img0.gif";
  document.getElementById(4).src = "img0.gif";

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>
  <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <link href="slotMachine.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Slot Machine!</h1>
      <h1>Try Your Luck!!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="game">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="img0.gif" id="1"></td>
          <td><img src="img0.gif" id="2"></td>
          <td><img src="img0.gif" id="3"></td>
          <td><img src="img0.gif" id="4"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="play">
      <button id="stop" onClick="pull()"> Pull </button>
      <button id="reset" onClick="start()"> Reset </button>
    </div>
    <div id="result">
      <p id="answer"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="slotMachine.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: @doutriforce It will be converted to a string.

Comment: @Barmar, where? I'm a noob, not finding where he does that.

Comment: It should be done automatically by Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar, oh, i see. Thank you!

Comment: Tnere's no error in your stack snippet.

Comment: What line does your browser tell you this is happening on? Double check your code and be sure it looks as it does here because I'm not able to reproduce your error. Everything working fine.